# Is this noise my trackpad making normal?

Tags: audio, hardware, trackpad

I just purchased the [Pixen](https://pixenapp.com/) app because it seems to be a popular one for making pixel art. However a wierd noise is coming from the computer now, one that I haven't heard before, and I've had this Macbook pro (the new model) for about a month.

I'm not sure whether it's a bug or not, since it's only coming from one specific action.

Specifically, it's when I use the "pattern paintbrush". I think a video will be more illustrative. Here's a link to watch the video on Google drive. It's about 20 seconds:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M6cUk8zj2xODtSVXCDD79lulibKwcFBE/view

I'm just wondering if I should stop running this program because something funky is happening, or if I shouldn't worry about it. My computer works fine other than except for the "b" key often enters doubles but I doubbt that's related. I've never heard a sound like this bbefore and I didn't know the computer could make it.

Comment: Just checking it's not coming from the haptic feedback of the trackpad?

Comment: @JMY1000 yes, it is. I posted an answer myself at the same moment you commented. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out, it's part of the "haptic feedback" which is configurable in System Preferences => Trackpad:

[image]